# Blocking Behaviour - Concurrent Data Structures Java

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, synchronization

I'm currently running a highly concurrent benchmark which accesses a `ConcurrentSkipList` from the Java collections. I'm finding that threads are getting blocked within that method, more precisely here:

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:828)    
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.get(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1626)
```

(This is obtained through, over 10 seconds interval, printing the stack trace of each individual thread).  This is still not resolved after minutes

Is this is an expected behaviour of collections? What are the concurrent other collections likely to experience blocking?

Having tested, it, I exhibit similar behaviour with `ConcurrentHashMap`s:

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:994)
```

Comment: Share your code with us

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking"? The `ConcurentSkipListMap` is a non-blocking data structure, so you should never see it blocked because it's waiting for a lock. It _does_ use [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), so if there's high contention in your benchmark it might just be getting stuck due to repeated failures. How are you determining that it's "blocked"?

Answer (score 6):

This could well be a spurious result.

When you ask Java for a dump of all its current stack traces, it tells each thread to wait when it gets to a yield point, then it captures the traces, and then it resumes all the threads. As you can imagine, this means that yield points are over-represented in these traces; these include synchronized methods, `volatile` accesses, etc. `ConcurrentSkipListMap.head`, a `volatile` field, is accessed in `doGet`.

See [this paper](http://pl.cs.colorado.edu/papers/mytkowicz-pldi10.pdf) for a more detailed analysis.

Solaris Studio has a profiler that captures stack traces from the OS and translates them to Java stack traces. This does away with the bias toward yield points and gives you more accurate results; you might find that `doGet` goes away almost entirely. I've only had luck running it on Linux, and even then it's not out-of-the-box. If you're interested, ask me in the comments how to set it up, I'd be happy to help.

As an easier approach, you could wrap your calls to `ConcurrentSkipList.get` with `System.nanoTime()` to get a sanity check on whether this is really where your time is going. Figure out how much time you're spending in that method, and confirm whether it's about what you'd expect given that the profiler says you're spending such-and-such percent of your time in that method.

Shameless self-plug:  I created a [simple program that demonstrates this](https://github.com/yshavit/java-profiling-breaker) a few months ago for a presentation at work. If you run it against a profiler, it should show that `SpinWork.work` appears a lot, while `HardWork.work` doesn't show up at all -- even though the latter actually takes a lot more time. It doesn't contain yield points.

Comment: If you want to wrap get() with nanoTime(), be aware that the latter can take anywhere from 1µs to 10ns, depending on hardware and OS. Also take a look at nanoTime’s granularity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't blocking in its truest form.  Blocking implies the suspension of thread activity.  ConcurrentSkipListMap is non-blocking, it will spin until is succeeds.  But it also guarantees it will eventually succeed (that is it shouldn't get into an infinite loop)

That being said, unless you are doing many many gets and many many puts asynchronously I don't see how you can be spending so much time in this method.

If you can re-create it with an example and share with us that may help.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentHashMap.get` is a volatile read, which means, the CPU must finish all outstanding writes before it can perform the read. This is called a STORE/LOAD barrier. Depending on how much is going on in the other thread/cores, this can take a long time. See https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html.